# Элемент заходит на ползунок

Tags: html, css, html5

`github-corner`, помещенный в блок `aside` выходит на ползунок прокрутки с правой стороны окна браузера. Кому не трудно, помогите с правкой, пожалуйста.

https://jsfiddle.net/628ckd69/1/

```css
body,
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}

body:before,
.cf:before,
body:after,
.cf:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

body:after,
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after,
*::before,
*::after {
  *behavior: url("js/vendor/boxsizing.htc");
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

img,
video,
audio,
embed,
object,
input,
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}


/*   STYLE   */

@import 'reset.css';
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:400italic,700italic,400,700");
html {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

a {
  color: #99f;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  color: #ff6347;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #aaa;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.content,
.sidebar {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 2em;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ff6347;
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar {
    order: 2;
  }
}

.sidebar img {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar img {
    display: none;
  }
}

.sidebar nav {
  font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.sidebar nav>a,
.sidebar nav>strong {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ff4726;
  border-top: 0;
}

.sidebar nav>a:first-child,
.sidebar nav>strong:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #ff4726;
}

.sidebar nav>a:hover,
.sidebar nav>strong {
  background: #ff5537;
}

.sidebar p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.sidebar p a {
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  flex: 2;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content {
    order: 1;
  }
}

.logo {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .logo {
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
}

.meow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  top: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.meow:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

pre,
code {
  background: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

code {
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

pre code {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin-left: 1.2em;
}

.permalink {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 0.7em;
  border: 0.3em solid transparent;
  margin: -0.3em 0 0 -1.3em;
  font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.permalink:before {
  content: '#';
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar .credit {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    margin: auto auto 1.5rem;
  }
}

.github-corner:hover .octo-arm {
  animation: octocat-wave 560ms ease-in-out
}

@keyframes octocat-wave {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  20%,
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  40%,
  80% {
    transform: rotate(10deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
      <a href="#">#LINK</a>
    </nav>

    <a href="#" class="github-corner" aria-label="View source on Github" target="_blank"><svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="fill:#f44336; color:#ECEFF1; position: absolute; top: 0; border: 0; right: 0;" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M0,0 L115,115 L130,115 L142,142 L250,250 L250,0 Z"></path><path d="M128.3,109.0 C113.8,99.7 119.0,89.6 119.0,89.6 C122.0,82.7 120.5,78.6 120.5,78.6 C119.2,72.0 123.4,76.3 123.4,76.3 C127.3,80.9 125.5,87.3 125.5,87.3 C122.9,97.6 130.6,101.9 134.4,103.2" fill="currentColor" style="transform-origin: 130px 106px;" class="octo-arm"></path><path d="M115.0,115.0 C114.9,115.1 118.7,116.5 119.8,115.4 L133.7,101.6 C136.9,99.2 139.9,98.4 142.2,98.6 C133.8,88.0 127.5,74.4 143.8,58.0 C148.5,53.4 154.0,51.2 159.7,51.0 C160.3,49.4 163.2,43.6 171.4,40.1 C171.4,40.1 176.1,42.5 178.8,56.2 C183.1,58.6 187.2,61.8 190.9,65.4 C194.5,69.0 197.7,73.2 200.1,77.6 C213.8,80.2 216.3,84.9 216.3,84.9 C212.7,93.1 206.9,96.0 205.4,96.6 C205.1,102.4 203.0,107.8 198.3,112.5 C181.9,128.9 168.3,122.5 157.7,114.1 C157.9,116.9 156.7,120.9 152.7,124.9 L141.0,136.5 C139.8,137.7 141.6,141.9 141.8,141.8 Z" fill="currentColor" class="octo-body"></path></svg></a>

  </aside>

  <main class="content">
    <header class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="./Iteration — Stylus_files/octocat.svg" alt="Stylus"></a>
    </header>

    <div class="docs">
      <h1>Iteration</h1>
      <h2 id="mixins">
        <a class="permalink" title="Link to this place" href="#"></a>Mixins</h2>

      <p>Below we define <code class="highlighter-rouge">apply()</code>, conditionally utilizing all the <code class="highlighter-rouge">arguments</code> so that comma-delimited <em>and</em> expression <strong>true</strong> lists are supported:</p>

      <p>Paragraph</p>

      <div class="highlighter-rouge">
        <pre class="highlight"><code>code</code></pre>
      </div>

      <p>Paragraph</p>

      <div class="highlighter-rouge">
        <pre class="highlight"><code>code</code></pre>
      </div>

      <p>Paragraph</p>

      <div class="highlighter-rouge">
        <pre class="highlight"><code>code</code></pre>
      </div>

    </div>


  </main>
</div>
```

Нужно как на второй картинке, а сейчас как на первой:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Эм.. А надо-то как?

Comment: Ну, чтобы картинка была на одной линии с сайдбаром, по оси Y (сдвиг влево на расстояние, равное ширине скролла)

Comment: [вот так](https://s4.postimg.org/eand5eezh/image.png), вместо того, что [сейчас](https://s4.postimg.org/afjz2tvtp/image.png)

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте вместо Вашего svg этот код

```
<svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="fill:#f44336; color:#ECEFF1; position: absolute; top: 0; border: 0; right: 17px;" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M0,0 L115,115 L130,115 L142,142 L250,250 L250,0 Z"></path><path d="M128.3,109.0 C113.8,99.7 119.0,89.6 119.0,89.6 C122.0,82.7 120.5,78.6 120.5,78.6 C119.2,72.0 123.4,76.3 123.4,76.3 C127.3,80.9 125.5,87.3 125.5,87.3 C122.9,97.6 130.6,101.9 134.4,103.2" fill="currentColor" style="transform-origin: 130px 106px;" class="octo-arm"></path><path d="M115.0,115.0 C114.9,115.1 118.7,116.5 119.8,115.4 L133.7,101.6 C136.9,99.2 139.9,98.4 142.2,98.6 C133.8,88.0 127.5,74.4 143.8,58.0 C148.5,53.4 154.0,51.2 159.7,51.0 C160.3,49.4 163.2,43.6 171.4,40.1 C171.4,40.1 176.1,42.5 178.8,56.2 C183.1,58.6 187.2,61.8 190.9,65.4 C194.5,69.0 197.7,73.2 200.1,77.6 C213.8,80.2 216.3,84.9 216.3,84.9 C212.7,93.1 206.9,96.0 205.4,96.6 C205.1,102.4 203.0,107.8 198.3,112.5 C181.9,128.9 168.3,122.5 157.7,114.1 C157.9,116.9 156.7,120.9 152.7,124.9 L141.0,136.5 C139.8,137.7 141.6,141.9 141.8,141.8 Z" fill="currentColor" class="octo-body"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Отступ от края заметен при просмотре на мобильных устройствах с сенсорным экраном -- том ползунок не отображается ( [см. картинку](http://i.imgur.com/uJvpVDL.jpg) ).

Comment: вот, добавление `position: relative;` родителю выравнивает по границе сайдбара, но при этом иконка скроллится вместе с этим сайдбаром ( [см. картинку](http://i.imgur.com/e8pNUMF.gif) ). А нужна она мне -- прижатой к верхнему углу.

Comment: тогда может такой вариант, прописать у svg элемента position: fixed; и right: 17px; а для мобильных устройств задать @media (max-width: 768px) {
  right: 0px;
} . Брейкпоинт 768 можно заменить на необходимый для вас

Comment: Вобщем, закрыл скроллы через стили,с изменением цвета

`::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5em;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ff6347;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ff6347;
}

body {
  scrollbar-face-color: #ff6347;
  scrollbar-track-color: #ff6347;
}`

Comment: Благодарен за помощь и уделенное время,

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>

/*   RESET   */

body, .cf {*zoom: 1;}
body:before, .cf:before,
body:after, .cf:after {
 content: ''; display: table;}
body:after, .cf:after {clear: both;}

*,
*:before, *:after,
*::before, *::after {
 *behavior: url("js/vendor/boxsizing.htc");
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;}

html {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;}

body {width: 100%;}

img,video,audio,embed,object,input,iframe {
 max-width: 100%;}

/*   STYLE   */

@import 'reset.css';
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:400italic,700italic,400,700");

html {
 font-family: 'Vollkorn', sans-serif;
 color: #444;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 14px;
 overflow-y: auto;}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html {font-size: 16px;}
}

a {color: #99f;}

a:hover {text-decoration: none;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin-top: 3rem;
 margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
 line-height: 1.1em;
 color: #ff6347;
 font-weight: normal;}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #aaa;}

p {margin-bottom: 1rem;}

img {max-width: 100%;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

.wrap {
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .wrap {flex-direction: row;}
}

.content, .sidebar {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 padding: 2em;}

.sidebar {
 background: #ff6347;
 flex: 1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 0.5em;}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar {order: 2;}
}

.sidebar img {
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar img {display: none;}
}

.sidebar nav {
 font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin-bottom: 2rem;}

.sidebar nav > a,
.sidebar nav > strong {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 1em;
 border: 1px solid #ff4726;
 border-top: 0;}

.sidebar nav > a:first-child,
.sidebar nav > strong:first-child {
 border-top: 1px solid #ff4726;}

.sidebar nav > a:hover,
.sidebar nav > strong {
 background: #ff5537;}

.sidebar p {font-size: 1.1em;}
.sidebar p a {color: #fff;}

.content {
 flex: 2;
 position: relative;}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content {order: 1;}
}

.logo {display: none;}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .logo {
 display: block;
 width: 130px;
 margin-bottom: 2rem;}
}

.meow {
 position: absolute;
 width: 32px;
 top: 2em;
 right: 2em;
 opacity: 0.5;}

.meow:hover {
 opacity: 0.75;}

pre, code {
 background: #fafafa;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 0.85rem;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;}

code {
 padding: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 0;}

pre code {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;}

ul, ol {margin-left: 1.2em;}

.permalink {
 float: left;
 width: 0;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-right: 0.7em;
 border: 0.3em solid transparent;
 margin: -0.3em 0 0 -1.3em;
 font-family: 'Unica One', sans-serif;
 color: #ccc;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;}

.permalink:before {content: '#';}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar .credit {
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 margin: auto auto 1.5rem;}
}

.github-corner:hover .octo-arm{
  animation:octocat-wave 560ms ease-in-out}
@keyframes 
  octocat-wave {0%,100%{transform:rotate(0)}
 20%,60% {transform:rotate(-25deg)}
 40%,80% {transform:rotate(10deg)}}
</style>
```

```html
<body>


<div class="wrap">

 <aside class="sidebar">
  <nav>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
   <a href="#">#LINK</a>
  </nav>



<a href="#" class="github-corner" aria-label="View source on Github" target="_blank"><svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="fill:#f44336; color:#ECEFF1; position: absolute; top: 0; border: 0; right:2.6%;" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M0,0 L115,115 L130,115 L142,142 L250,250 L250,0 Z"></path><path d="M128.3,109.0 C113.8,99.7 119.0,89.6 119.0,89.6 C122.0,82.7 120.5,78.6 120.5,78.6 C119.2,72.0 123.4,76.3 123.4,76.3 C127.3,80.9 125.5,87.3 125.5,87.3 C122.9,97.6 130.6,101.9 134.4,103.2" fill="currentColor" style="transform-origin: 130px 106px;" class="octo-arm"></path><path d="M115.0,115.0 C114.9,115.1 118.7,116.5 119.8,115.4 L133.7,101.6 C136.9,99.2 139.9,98.4 142.2,98.6 C133.8,88.0 127.5,74.4 143.8,58.0 C148.5,53.4 154.0,51.2 159.7,51.0 C160.3,49.4 163.2,43.6 171.4,40.1 C171.4,40.1 176.1,42.5 178.8,56.2 C183.1,58.6 187.2,61.8 190.9,65.4 C194.5,69.0 197.7,73.2 200.1,77.6 C213.8,80.2 216.3,84.9 216.3,84.9 C212.7,93.1 206.9,96.0 205.4,96.6 C205.1,102.4 203.0,107.8 198.3,112.5 C181.9,128.9 168.3,122.5 157.7,114.1 C157.9,116.9 156.7,120.9 152.7,124.9 L141.0,136.5 C139.8,137.7 141.6,141.9 141.8,141.8 Z" fill="currentColor" class="octo-body"></path></svg></a>



 </aside>


 <main class="content">
  <header class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="./Iteration — Stylus_files/octocat.svg" alt="Stylus"></a>
  </header>

  <div class="docs">
   <h1>Iteration</h1>
   <h2 id="mixins"><a class="permalink" title="Link to this place" href="#"></a>Mixins</h2>

   <p>Below we define <code class="highlighter-rouge">apply()</code>, conditionally utilizing all the <code class="highlighter-rouge">arguments</code> so that comma-delimited <em>and</em> expression <strong>true</strong> lists are supported:</p>

   <p>Paragraph</p>

   <div class="highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code>code</code></pre></div>

   <p>Paragraph</p>

   <div class="highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code>code</code></pre></div>

   <p>Paragraph</p>

   <div class="highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code>code</code></pre></div>

   </div>


</main>
</div>




</body>
```

Comment: Подбери смещение в svg позицию right:2.6%;

Comment: Если задать отступ справа в процентах/пикселах/em, сильно видна разница наложений элементов на сенсорных дисплеях, где скролл не отображается. Можно, конечно, сделать фон картинки прозрачным, но это не выход.